# Savon is not logging it's output to production.log, even with logging enabled and set to :info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging, savon

I have all three environments (test, development, production) displaying log output at the :info level, through `config.log_level = :info` in their respective .rb files.

When I start my local Rails server with `rails s`, Savon output appears in the console when there are requests which is what I expect. But this output is not logged to the actual `development.log` file. The same thing occurs on a production environment, which is where I'd really like to see Savon's output.

I have this block in my application.rb:

```
Savon.configure do |config|
  config.env_namespace = :soapenv
  config.log = true
  config.logger = Rails.logger
  config.log_level = :info
  config.pretty_print_xml = true
end
```

Which does configure whether or not I can see the logging in the console. But how do I actual write it to *.log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem on [GitHub](https://github.com/savonrb/savon/issues/370). The trick is to configure the variables directly within the Savon::Model client.

Answer (score 2):

for me it was the order :/ 
the 'log' should come prior to 'logger'

- config.log = true
- config.logger = Rails.logger